# Update GeForce driver on top of Lenovo's Nvidia Optimus driver package?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, optimus

Lenovo offers Optimus graphic driver updates that always seem to reference old/outdated versions of the official Nvidia GeForce driver.

I realize that the GeForce driver does not include the Optimus software, which is required for laptops with two graphics chips like my ThinkPad Yoga 15. So the question is whether I can update GeForce separately, while keeping everything else in the Lenovo package unaffected.

**Example** - newest drivers as of today, 8/16/2016:

- Lenovo Optimus Driver 10.18.1**3.5747** [link](http://support.lenovo.com/de/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/ThinkPad-Yoga-Series-laptops/ThinkPad-Yoga-15/downloads/DS104290)
- GeForce Driver **372.54** [link](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/105853)

The bolded part in the Lenovo version indicates that the packaged GeForce driver is **357.47**, which seems pretty old compared to 372.54.

Is it safe to install the newest GeForce driver on top of Lenovo's Optimus driver - i.e. will the non-GeForce drivers in the Lenovo package be unaffected if I install the GeForce driver separately?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to? New game not working as expected, etc? If not, leave it alone. 357 is about 6 months old, avoids the 36x debacle & should work for most things. It's the kind of thing I wouldn't start playing with until Lenovo stop updating the drivers themselves [6 months to 2 years from manufacture usually]

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, that's good advice. There's no particular reason I wanted to update other than the seemingly outdated version number.